# Cosa significa "polvere manomessa" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Risuonarono, fra la **polvere manomessa**, gagliarde rampogne che datavano dal milleseicentodieci, dal milleseicentoquindici: come gli anni di sdegnoso silenzio, d'esilio, di separazione e disinteresse, pesassero meno di un'ora.

Penso che si riferisca alla polvere dello studio di Orazio Gentileschi a Londra, menzionata prima nel romanzo:

> Le giovavano certe faccenduole domestiche -- lavare fazzoletti, lucidare una scatola o un piatto -- che a poco a poco s'era messa ad amare e a prodigare senza necessità intorno al vecchio; dicendosi, al modo delle donne casalinghe inveterate, che lui ne aveva bisogno, che stava a lei il combattere la gloriosa polvere dello studio: perché Orazio non vivesse in tanta sporcizia, appena soccorsa da una scopata dei garzoni. Cominiciava a ragionare [...]. E poiché Orazio usava assentarsi all'improvviso e uscire senza dir dove andasse, era un'avventura insinuarsi, con cencio e piumaccio, fra telai, cartoni, tele arrotolate, quaderni, vecchie lettere.

Ho letto tutte le accezioni di [manomettere nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manomettere/), ma non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda "manomessa" nel primo brano. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Mi servirebbe più contesto per esserne sicuro al 100%, ma credo che il significato in questione sia quello sotto la lettera (c) del dizionario Treccani: *disordinare, travisare*. Immagino che la protagonista sia in un posto dove la polvere tende ad accumularsi indisturbata e che lei l'abbia, per l'appunto, disturbata.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ho aggiornato il testo della domanda per cercar di farlo. Penso che tu abbia ragione.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dato il contesto credo che il significato in questione sia quello sotto la lettera (c) del dizionario Treccani: *disordinare, travisare*. La protagonista è nello studio di Orazio Gentileschi, un posto dove la polvere tende ad accumularsi indisturbata, e lei, per l'appunto, la disturba con le sue pulizie.

Comment: Ops, Orazio non Oreste! Scusate per il lapsus... Sto evidentemente pensando troppo ad Elektra questi giorni :)

Comment: "Travisare" col significato figurato di "far mutare l'aspetto"?

Comment: È come lo interpreterei io. Inoltre non dimentichiamoci che la parola *manomettere* è sufficentemente vicina alla sua origine etimologica *mettere mano* che usare una per l'altra è perfettamente comprensibile, almeno ad un parlante nativo. Personalmente non lo userei, ma non mi lascia neanche troppo scandalizzato, specie in una prosa arcaicizzante.